# Как получить значение result за пределами function(err, result)?

Tags: node-redis

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient();
client.hgetall('frameworks', function(err, result){
       console.log(result);
   });
```

Не получается вернуть result значение снаружи этой функции. Есть ли у вас реально работающий код с решением данной задачи? Уже читал, про промисы, колбэки, вложенные функции... Ничего не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, я что-то не понял, но разве вот так не сработает?

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient();
let outerResult;

client.hgetall('frameworks', function(err, result){
       outerResult = result;
});
console.log(outerResult);
```

Comment: Нет, за пределами не сработает. Проверенно. Похоже, что функции Redis асинхронно работают,

Comment: Хотя в документации Redis говорится, что все работает в одном потоке. Тогда не понятно все же, почему нельзя получить значение result за пределами колбэк функции?